# I want to create a special column in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I need your help
I want to create a special column in sharepoint
Similar to an ID column with a beginning of 00000001
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a calculated column.

```
=CONCATENATE("000001",ID)
```

[image]

If you want to create a column that does not depend on the ID, you can try to create a custom column type.

Comment: Look the first time when I write the code it does the job and when you enter it again it gives me 000000
Does not combine with id